# how to configure identity source for api gateway from context

Tags: authorization, aws-api-gateway

I am configuring an custom lambda auth for api gateway with a swagger file.

I want the lambda auth function to cache requests through a combination of http method and an "Authorization" header

according to AWS
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-authorizer.html i need to set a comma seperated string in `identitySource` under `x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer` in an undocumented schema.

Apparently to access the "Authorization" header i need to put `method.request.header.Authorization` Although i didn't find where the exact schema of this string is documented.

Now i want to access the `httpMethod` on the `context` and am puzzled how the string in identitySource needs to look like. The UI also didn't seem to work.